# Passing variable to another sub in a for loop if

Tags: vba, global-variables, parameter-passing

Having the error below in my code shown below,

> Compile Error
>
> Wrong Number of of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Public Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim ShNameRow As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

            Set T1 = Range("A" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
            Set T2 = Range("E" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 2)
            Set T3 = Range("K" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
            Set y = Application.Union(T1, T2, T3)
            y.Select
            Selection.Copy


            ShNameRow = 13 + i
            'Error with passing this variable
            CopyData_Click (ShNameRow)

        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyData_Click()
    'Testing variable
    MsgBox (ShNameRow)
End Sub
```

-

### UPDATE

I tried both that example of passing variable from one sub to another because I feel is more applicable with my code.

Public Sub ListBox1_Click()

```
Dim ShNameRow As Integer
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

        Set T1 = Range("A" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
        Set T2 = Range("E" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 2)
        Set T3 = Range("K" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
        Set y = Application.Union(T1, T2, T3)
        y.Select
        Selection.Copy


        ShNameRow = 13 + i
        'Error with passing this variable
        CopyData_Click (ShNameRow)

    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyData_Click(ListboxShNameRow As Integer)
MsgBox (ListboxShNameRow)
End Sub
```

Which brings another compile error on, displayed by block quote below

```
Private Sub CopyData_Click(ListboxShNameRow As Integer)
```

> Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: @ashleedawg `CopyData_Click (ShNameRow)` Gives Error

Comment: Yeah I see what's going on... you have a few potential problems but I'll focus on your question in an answer, ....

Comment: @ashleedawg just got back from dinnner, give me some time to test it out, wasn't expecting such prompt response. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** after OP question editing and clarifications

so `CopyData_Click` is a button event handler ...

then you have to ways to set a variable inside `ListBox1_Click()` and use it in `CopyData_Click()`

1) use a *Module scoped* variable

declare `ShNameRow` as a *Module scoped* variable, i.e. a variable that is "seen" inside any sub/function inside the same module (which in your case is your user form code module

to do this just place `Dim ShNameRow As Integer` at the very top of the module

and then just call CopyData_Click passing with no parameters (as its *signature* requires)

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim ShNameRow As Integer

    Public Sub ListBox1_Click()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim T1 As Range, T2 As Range, T3 As Range, y As Range
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

                Set T1 = Range("A" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
                Set T2 = Range("E" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 2)
                Set T3 = Range("K" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
                Set y = Application.Union(T1, T2, T3)
                y.Select
                Selection.Copy

                ShNameRow = 13 + i

                CopyData_Click ' call 'CopyData' button 'Click' event handler

            End If
        Next i

    End Sub


    Private Sub CopyData_Click()
        MsgBox ShNameRow ' 'ShNameRow ' variable can be used inside this sub because it's a module scoped variable. i.e. it's "seen" throughout every sub or function inside the module on top of which it's declared 

        ... rest of your code (I guess you are "pasting" the already copied range)
    End Sub
```

2) use `Tag` property of your `UserForm` object to store the wanted information

```
    Option Explicit


    Public Sub ListBox1_Click()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim T1 As Range, T2 As Range, T3 As Range, y As Range
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

                Set T1 = Range("A" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
                Set T2 = Range("E" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 2)
                Set T3 = Range("K" & i + 13).Resize(26 - i, 1)
                Set y = Application.Union(T1, T2, T3)
                y.Select
                Selection.Copy

                Me.Tag = 13 + i
                'Error with passing this variable
                CopyData_Click

            End If
        Next i

    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyData_Click()
        Dim ShNameRow As Integer ' declare 'ShNameRow' as a local variable, i.e. it's "seen" only inside the sub/function it's declared in
        ShNameRow = Me.Tag ''Me' is the keyword referring to the User Form object whose module code you're inside
        MsgBox ShNameRow

        ... rest of your code (I guess you are "pasting" the already copied range) 
    End Sub
```

Comment: what kind of error and which line is throwing that error?

Comment: Error = **Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name** Code = `Private Sub CopyData_Click(ShNameRow As Integer)`

Comment: Have yet to tested it out, I know there's the tag function under the userform properties but, what's to be in there? Not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from one sub to another can be done a few ways, but here's the two you're mixing up:

### Global Variables

```
Public myGlobalVariable As String

Sub myMainSub()
    myGlobalVariable = InputBox("Enter a word:")
    myOtherSub
End Sub


Sub myOtherSub()
    MsgBox "Any sub can see 'Public' variables : " & myGlobalVariable
End Sub
```

### Passing variable as Parameters

```
Sub myMainSub2()
    Dim myVariableWithinSub As String
     myVariableWithinSub = InputBox("Enter a word:")
     myOtherSub2 (myVariableWithinSub)
End Sub


Sub myOtherSub2(variableIgotFromOtherSub As String)
    MsgBox "Variables can be passed as 'Parameters' like this." & _
        vbLf & "See? : " & variableIgotFromOtherSub
End Sub
```

This question will likely be closed because it's a pretty basic thing that you should have Googled and figured out, but I know it's hard to get started when you don't know what to search for.

Try my examples (separately) in your module and experiment so you can see the differences.  **Please** Google the terms "Global Variables Excel VBA" and "Passing Parameters Excel VBA" to learn more about both.

Also I highly recommend that you put `Option Explicit` as the first line of *every module*.  This will seem like it's causing errors but it will prevent future frustration for yourself, by forcing you to properly declare & handle all variables, objects, properties, etc.

Couple things to note about the code in your example:

- I fixed your indenting.  Indenting doesn't change the way the code runs, but it makes it much easier for you (and others) to read and troubleshoot.
- Also I moved your `Dim` statement from inside your loop to the beginning. You don't want anything inside the loop that you don't want running over and over and over (like declaring a variable). ...Technically I shouldn't have changed your code in your question (outside of cosmetic things like indenting) but it was force of habit (and an easy mistake for you to make!)

Good luck!

Comment: I updated my codes above after testing them out. Got an error with latter sub

Comment: What error?  What code did you use?  You're likely still using incorrect syntax somewhere, since the examples I posted are very simple (and function properly on their own.)   **Did you Google the terms that I suggested** in my answer?

Comment: (By the way, ***"code"*** is always singular.  *"Codes"* is not a word, when used in the context of programming (and makes me cringe every time!).  More info **[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20456/282305)**). ☺